# Why php version option for Laravel project is disable?

Tags: phpstorm

I created new PHP/Laravel 7 application and in My PhpStorm 2019.2.5 I can not set PHP for this project:

[image]

Option where I set php version for this project is disable...

Why and how to correct it ?

Comment: Disable sync with composer.json... or set the right PHP version right there in composer.json. P.S. In newer PhpStorm versions you can change it even when sync is enabled (but it will reset it back on next project opening if sync is enabled).

Comment: In composer.json of my project I have :
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5|^8.0",

Is it option I have to edit ? How ?

Comment: Could be that your version does not understand this 2 versions format... Disable the sync and it should be working.

Comment: Where have I to disable the sync ?

Comment: Expand "PHP" node on your screenshot and look for "Composer" node. **P.S.** Pro hint: Settings screen has a search box (top left corner): try it -- it's there just for such cases.